# A question conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, projection

Define $M(Z_1, \dots, Z_n)$ to mean the closed subspace of $L^2$ consisting of all random variables in $L^2$ of the form $\phi(Z_1, \dots, Z_n)$ for some Borel function $\phi: R^n \rightarrow R$. Is it true for any $X, Y_1, Y_2, \dots , Y_n$ random variables that

$$E[X \ | \ \bar{\operatorname{sp}}\{Y_1, \dots, Y_n \}  ] =E[X | M(Y_1, \dots , Y_n]$$

where $\bar{\operatorname{sp}}$ is the closed span of $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ in $L^2$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by conditional expectation with respect to a subspace of $\mathbb L^2$?

Comment: It's defined as the projection on the Hilbert space $L^2$ see:


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823751/on-a-property-of-conditional-expectation-when-the-random-variable-is-multivariat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no, even when $n=1$. For example if $X=Y_1^2$, then $ E[X | M(Y_1, \dots , Y_n)]=X$ but in general $Y_1^2$ is not an element of the closure of the subspace generated by the constants and $Y_1$.